# Re-initialise directive on controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a carousel that loads a bunch of items from an array, but a directive is being used to show the carousel.

I want to remove an item from a list such as "street parties" if something gets selected, but as the list of items seems to binded to a directive how can reload the directive? I have seen similar questions but I cant seem to get anything to work yet.. Thank you.

In my controller I have the various items like this

```
this.eventProducts.push({
                link: "/quote/bar-and-bat-mitzvah-insurance",
                image: "/Content/Images/policies/bar-mitzvah.jpg",
                name: "Bar and Bat Mitzvahs"
            });
            this.eventProducts.push({
                link: "/quote/street-party-insurance",
                image: "/Content/Images/policies/street-party.jpg",
                name: "Street Parties"
            });
            this.eventProducts.push({
                link: "/quote/conference-and-meetings-insurance",
                image: "/Content/Images/policies/conference.jpg",
                name: "Conferences and Meetings"
            });
```

Then I have this directive which sets the carousel

```
angular.module("App")
        .controller("HomepageController", HomepageController)
        .config(["$routeProvider", HomepageController.routing])
        .directive("owlCarousel", () => {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                transclude: false,
                link: (scope:any) => {
                    scope.initCarousel = (element) => {
                        // provide any default options you want
                        var defaultOptions = {
                        };
                        var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr("data-options"));
                        // combine the two options objects
                        for (var key in customOptions) {
                            defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
                        }
                        // init carousel
                        (<any>$(element)).owlCarousel(defaultOptions);
                    };
                }
            };
        })
        .directive("owlCarouselItem", [() => {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                transclude: false,
                link:  (scope, element) => {
                    // wait for the last item in the ng-repeat then call init
                    if (scope.$last) {
                        scope.initCarousel(element.parent());
                    }
                }
            };
        }]);
```

And in the HTML the items are being loaded like this

```
<div class="row homepage-events">
    <div class="homepage-heading"><h2 class="text-center">A Selection of our Most Popular Event Insurance Policies</h2></div>
    <data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="{navigation: false, pagination: true, rewindNav : true}">
        <div class="carousel-item" owl-carousel-item="" data-ng-repeat="product in ::homepageController.eventProducts">
            <div class="">
                <div class="thumbnails thumbnail-style thumbnail-kenburn">
                    <div class="thumbnail-img">
                        <div class="overflow-hidden">
                            <a class="" href="{{::product.link}}">
                                <img data-ng-src="{{::product.image}}" alt="{{::product.altText}}" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <a class="btn-more2 hover-effect">Insurance for</a>
                        <a class="btn-more hover-effect" data-ng-href="{{::product.link}}">{{::product.name}}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </data-owl-carousel>
</div>
```

Comment: once you remove item from the list `digest cycle` should be triggered and `ng-repeat` will remove that item.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesnt seem to recognise when items are added or removed.. I tried doing this.scope.$apply(); to force it but I get an error "apply already in progress".

Comment: how about you create live demo of your code, jsfiddle or something else.

Comment: This is part of a big project.. so to include everything in jsfiddle would take a bit of time. When it first loads you see all the ten items in the carousel fine (I showed 3 but there are 10), there must be a straightforward way to re-trigger the init on the scope. The directive has created an islolated scope so is it tricky to re-init that?

Comment: by using `::` in binding you are killing two way binding, why are you doing that, try to remove it at least in ng-repeat.

Comment: I tried that but it made no difference.

Comment: and how you remove the item from the list?

Comment: Well first of all the angular controller calls a method to build the eventProducts array, then later I call the same method which passes a parameter to exclude an item in the array and rebuilds it, but the page is still the same. It only shows the items that were called when the constructor ran.

Comment: are you sure that you are removing item from the list, what method do you use something like `slice()`. It simply must work, if you remove `::` digest will trigger all two way binding and give a new values. you might have problem with removing items from list

Comment: It is the directive that is binding the array with the page, so i need the directive to call its init again.

Comment: the directive will show whatever data it is served with (even if it is changed in run-time as long as it is referenced correctly). your problem is not with directive, it is with data, i cannot help you without live demo or some more code. sorry.

Comment: Ok, the data is a simple array as I put at the top. Hmm strange. I feel I need to call the controller constructor again to make it re-initialise..